# Joining on composite primary key & separate components

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables that contain periodic snapshots of similar data. The first table contains a Surrogate Key as PK that is a simple concatenation of Id & Date, the PK is enforced as a constraint.
The second table has both columns separately, but enforces the PK on both columns.

How would I ideally join considering I have many records?

Table1 has 3 relevant columns:

- CustomerPk =  Table1.CustomerId || Table2.SnapshotDate (there is probably some casting going on in the back, but stored as one record)
- CustomerId (just a record)
- SnapshotDate (just a record with a monthly date)

Table2 has 2 relevant columns, which are together enforced as a PK:

- CustomerId (just a record)
- SnapshotDate (just a record with a monthly date)

How would I ideally join?

- on Table1.CustomerPk = Table2.CustomerId || to_number(TO_CHAR(Table2.SnapshotDate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))
- on Table1.CustomerId = Table2.CustomerId and Table1.SnapshotDate = Table2.SnapshotDate
- on Table1.CustomerId = Table2.CustomerId where Table1.SnapshotDate = Table2.SnapshotDate
- on left(Table1.CustomerPk, 12) = Table2.CustomerId and right(Table1.SnapshotDate, 19) = Table2.SnapshotDate

Some other suggestions? Trying out different things here but queries are long.

Comment: I would recommend you normalize the data and have either the PK/FK as a single column or two separate ones. Make sure the FK is enforced as a contraint; there's really no reason why not to do this. The conversion you need is really detrimental for the performance of any query. It places perfectly avoidable restrictions on the optimizer, and that means it has less options to optimize your queries.

Comment: If this is about performance, it may be helpful to avoid applying functions to one table or the other in order to allow the PK index to be used. If so, you'll need to keep one as-is and reformat the other as necessary to match it.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamRobertson. Am I correct in assuming I should keep the index on the larger, less performant table and use functions for formatting the second key?

Comment: @Kellerness probably, but it will depend on the query.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any specific rules or guidelines in this kind of optimization? Just testing?